# Parse on Android Emulator returns null deviceToken

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to test my app on emulator but I´m getting the device token with:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");

            }
    }
```

But `deviceToken` is null on emulator, how can I run on emulators?

Thanks